# Has anyone used partsim and if they have, where is the potentiometer?

Tags: amplifier, schematics, partsim

Thanks you all for reading. Lately I have been trying to use [www.partsim.com](http://www.partsim.com) to model a vintage synthesizer in hopes of building a real one with real hardware. However it's really expensive to do so and I don't know anything about electronics so I don't want to waste my time and energy if I'm not good enough to do the project. Was wondering if anyone has used it and if they know if there is a potentiometer object and a 2 pole - 3 way switch object.

Comment: Let me know if you still require help, otherwise can you select an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no potentiometer in partsim.

Why not just use two resistors and change the resistance as required?

Partsim is a simulator rather than a schematic package, so using the resistance values rather than an adjustable potentiometer should be fine, (to my knowledge tracks are not simulated).

Same again for the switch, just build two circuits, one switch and one unswitched, (again to my knowledge the sim does not model switching transients).

Alternatively, email digikey and ask them to generate a potentiometer for the sim, (support@partsim.com.)

Comment: I figured there wasn't any active controls but I guess that just means I have to get a little creative, thanks for your help.

Comment: @BobSaget If you found the answer useful, it doesn't cost anything to upvote.  Also,may be worth checking out ltspice which is also free.

Comment: I did thanks! it wouldn't let me upvote both which was annoying so I just picked who answered first.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a potentiometer or a mechanical switch either. I believe this may be due to simulation limitations of partsim, parts that could be "manipulated" during simulation are not present. If you would like to stick with partsim, I'd recommend simulation using two resistors instead of a potentiometer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9T5Hk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By changing R1 and R2 values, keeping the constraint R3 = R1 + R2, you can  replicate the effects of the moving potentiometer cursor. For a more "hands-on" experience, in which you can flip switches and move potentiometers mid-simulation, I personally prefer software such as NI Multisim or Labcenter Proteus. (Disclaimer: I've never used partsim before)

Comment: I would love to try those programs but I think they are really expensive. I will have to stick with partsim and just be crafty like doing things like this, or just manually changing values works too. Thank you